# minimax depth first search game tree

Tags: tree, minimax

I want to build a game tree for nine men's morris game. I want to apply minimax algorithm on the tree for doing node evaluations. Minimax uses DFS to evaluate nodes. So should I build the tree first upto a given depth and then apply minimax or can the process of building the tree and evaluation occur together in recursive minimax DFS?

Thank you
Arvind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [iterative deepening depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can build and evaluate at the same time in a recursive minimax.
That is a good approach since it'll save memory space.

Actually, you can even apply [alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning) at the same time.

**Edit:** here is pseudocode from wiki [Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Pseudocode):

```
function integer minimax(node, depth)
    if node is a terminal node or depth == 0:
        return the heuristic value of node
    α = -∞
    for child in node: # evaluation is identical for both players 
        α = max(α, -minimax(child, depth-1))
    return α
```

Since we (probably) store a game / board state in each node, we could embed the
creation of game states
in the minimax algorithm, ie

```
function integer play_minimax(node, depth)
    if node is a terminal node or depth == 0:
        return the heuristic value of node
    α = -∞
    LOOP: # try all possible movements for this node/game state
        player = depth mod 2
        move = make_game_move(node, player)
        break if not any move
        α = max(α, -play_minimax(move, depth-1))
    return α
```

Comment: thanks..Is there a java implementation or pseudo code somewhere that I can refer to?